# Walking relationships in email templates in a workflow

Tags: workflow, email-template, relationships

I have a custom email address field on Account called Primary Email Address. We have also created a custom object off of account called Purchases. I want to be able to send an email to the Primary Email Address field on account every time a new Purchase record is added. Essentially, I want to walk up the child-parent relationship like so

> Purchase__c.Account__r.Primary_Email_Address__c

However, it appears Salesforce doesn't allow for this. The "Recipient Type" drop down options do not include related object fields.

I can obviously do this with APEX, but I don't want to. I could also create an email field on `Purchase__c` and copy the `Primary_Email_Address__c` value using another workflow or APEX, but I'm trying to avoid duplicating data in objects.

Ideally, I would like to walk the relationship to get to `Primary_Email_Address__c` from `Purchase__c`.

Comment: the relationship would be, from `Purchase__c` : `account__r.primaryEmail_Address__c`

Comment: Good catch. Are you also implying that this walk should be possible via Recipient Type?

Comment: are you trying to do this via a Workflow on `Purchase__c` with an Email Alert action? If yes, then you are correct. What you need is a workflow that first copies the value of `Account__r.primary_email_address__c` into a field of type Email on the `Purchase__c`, then a second workflow that executes the email alert using the `Purchase__c.Primary_email_address__c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it is not possible walk this relationship. What I ended up doing was creating an email field on the `Purchase__c` object, and using workflow to copy the email value from `Account`.